# Best way to model armor plate shin guard like the attached picture?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, geometry

I was wondering what the best approach to modeling the armor plates like the given picture. I've tried to box model it but I'm not getting similar results. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!
[image][1][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the basic shape of the thigh, cut some horizontal edge loops with the knife tool (<kbd>C</kbd> to cut through):

[image]

Extrude the faces along the normals (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]

Bevel the edges etc:

[image]

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you Moonboots.

Comment: Afterwards you could bake the normals in order to keep a low-poly mesh

Comment: I appreciate that. :)